# Why is it getting extra data

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

In the code I made a spreadsheet that records two random numbers every 10 seconds and add the numbers to three rows and when a certain condition was met it could end the loop but then I made it so that after the loop ends a new spreadsheet was created and the loop starts again. However when the loop starts again it adds extra rows with numbers to the sheet when I just want it to end at the same condition the first sheet ended at. I could not seem to figure out why I was getting extra rows filled with numbers

```
# global variable
globvar = 1
# start generate_random_number function
def generate_random_number():
    int1 = random.randint(55, 99)
    int2 = random.randint(1, 50)
    print('Numbers have been generated')
    return int1, int2
# end generate_random_number function

# start create_excel function
def create_excel():
    # call global
    global globvar
    #check file created and not
    if(globvar == 1):
        wb = Workbook()
        wb.remove_sheet(wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet'))
        wb.create_sheet('Test '+str(globvar))
        ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Test '+str(globvar))
        ws['A1'] = 'Random 1'
        ws['B1'] = 'Random 2'
        wb.save('sample.xlsx')
        print('Document created')
   else:
        wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
        wb.create_sheet('Test '+str(globvar))
        ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Test '+str(globvar))
        ws['A1'] = 'Random 1'
        ws['B1'] = 'Random 2'
        wb.save('sample.xlsx')
        print('Document created')
# end create_excel function

# start update_excel function
def update_excel():
    global globvar
    wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Test '+str(globvar))
    ws.append(generate_random_number())
    wb.save('sample.xlsx')
    print('Spreadsheet updated')
# end update_excel function

# start main function
def main():
    global globvar
    m = 1
    create_excel()
    update_excel()
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(update_excel)
    loop = True
    while loop:
        schedule.run_pending()
        m += 1
        print('Waiting...')
        time.sleep(10)
        if m == 3:
            schedule.run_pending()
            loop = False
            globvar +=1
            #print('Finished program. ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            #print('Starting program now.... ' +   str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            #main()
# end main function

# starts whole script here
print('Starting program now.... '+ str(datetime.datetime.now()))   
t = 1
while True:    
    main()
    t += 1
    if t == 3:
        break
print('Finished program. '+ str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Comment: Maybe be more specific about what "extra data" means.

Comment: After looking at the code again I thought the error might be the main being called again at the end of the main function, but when I comment it out and created a loop on main at the end I still get the extra data.

Comment: So I have the program add random number to three rows, but after the first sheet it adds numbers to the 6 rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding error python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079663/finding-error-python)

Comment: This is the third post on basically the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because more than 10 seconds have passed between increments of globvar. What will be happening is that you have 2 or more pending calls of `update_excel` running instead of 1 per increment.

That's not really surprising since you have a schedule of 10 seconds and a 10 second sleep meaning that any extra delays caused by code execution will make the loop take longer than 10 seconds and cause your scheduled tasks to queue.

Instead of using `schedule.every` just put your `update_excel` calls directly in your loop.

```
def main():
    ...
    create_excel()
    while loop:
        update_excel()
        time.sleep(10)
        m += 1
        if m == 3:
            globvar += 1
            return
```

Comment: Ok that resolves the extra rows but now when I run the whole program I am getting 2 sheets, first sheet is named Sheet with no numbers and then the second sheet named Test 2 with numbers. The sheet called Sheet should have been removed as stated in the create excel function and be replaced with Test 1

Comment: Never mind I figured out the issue I overlooked a line I did not change, thank you for the help with the extra rows.